# What to do about window trim pulling loose of the wall?

Tags: windows, trim

We had new windows installed about 7 years ago. Then 2 years ago we had the space remodeled, drywall put into replace the 1950's panelling. Included nhew trim around windows. Then we put blinds up that are an outside mount. Tonight i see the blind pulling away from the trim...but really its the trim starting to pulling  loose from the wall! What do we do? Not real handy and hubs is having hand surgery soon. Thanks in advance

Comment: call someone to help you

Comment: Yeah i get that. I guess what i really want to know is it a simple fix. I can wield a hammer etc. And really what is causing it! The blinds are heavy, but I've never had this happen before, so what can i do myself to fix and be sure it doesn't continue.

Comment: sounds like the blinds are attached to the trim ..... the trim is not attached very solidly to the wall ..... maybe the screws are too short and do not hit the wood inside the wall ..... it is not possible to guess where the structural components of the wall are (studs, etc) ...... you could get a stud finder and try to find the studs in the wall and then use wood screws to attach the trim to the studs

Comment: Windows usually come with 2X4 or 2X6 frames. Have you got the top trim attached to this frame? If not, you are relying on your drywall to support the blinds. Drywall is not good at that sort of thing. jstola has it essentially right, but I've never met a window that wasn't put into a tight 2X whatever frame. How far back from the wall surface is the window? Are your trim screws *at least* that deep? Good luck to husband. Hands are supposed to quickly and painlessly do what yo tell them.

Comment: Yes...i am positive that the knucklehead who put the trim up (not hubs) did not anchor into frames. I guess he never thought we would attach shades to it. I'm going to remove shades, find studs, use trim screws. Repair, sand, paint, reattach shades. I hope the shades can go up in same holes,  that would make it easier. Plus now i see vertical trim pulling away and drywall paper pulling!!!!  ...how long should said screws be?